# vb.net cancel SelectedIndexChanged and reselect previous item

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have a `ComboBox` and when a different item is selected some data need to be deleted.

To avoid accidentally deleting, I've added a confirm message on `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

This way, data are cancelled only after confirmation.

My problem is: **How can I also avoid changing of selected item when not confirmed?**

(I wish to mantain the previous selected index)

I noticed that I can't use `e.cancel` or `e.handled`

I also know that I could store actual value in a global variable and use it to restore previous value but I'm asking for a better solution (if it's possible).

**EDIT**
At the time, I'm storing the Index in a form level variable and I'm using a boolean to avoid executing the event twice. Below you can see my code:

```
Private Sub CBox_AmType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBox_AmType.SelectedIndexChanged
    If DontRunSelChange Then
        DontRunSelChange = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '...some code 
    Dim OkCanc As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Changing confirmation",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If OkCanc = vbCancel Then
            DontRunSelChange = True 'This to avoid running twice
            CBox_AmType.SelectedIndex = AmType_Index
            Exit Sub
        End If
    '...some code 
End sub
```

**EDIT 2**
The following is my attempt using Plutonix code:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxEx1_SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs) Handles ComboBoxEx1.SelectedIndexChanging
    Dim SN As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Changing confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If SN = DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.Lbl_Text.Text = Me.ComboBoxEx1.SelectedItem.ToString
End Sub
```

But the event is fired twice, called by the row:

```
MyBase.SelectedIndex = MyBase.Items.IndexOf(selectedObject)
```

Comment: Couldn't you do `onclientselectedindexchanged="return confirm('Are you sure?');"`

Comment: What is inefficient or not working with a form level variable?  On way would be to subclass the control (Listbox?  ComboBox?) and add a new event (eg `SelectedIndexChanging`) which would allow you to cancel the change.  All that does is internalize the same logic.

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, got it. I trust you and if you say so, I'll do as you say. ;) Thanks

Comment: You ought not need that form level var.  When the selected index changes, a NEW event called `SelectedIndexChanging` fires.  Do whatever validation you need to do there.  If you want to disallow the change, set `e.Cancel` to True in the event.  When you do that, the regular `SelectedIndexChanged` event does not fire and the old index is retained.  The control is setup to do that stuff for you.

Comment: @Plutonix " When the selected index changes, a NEW event called SelectedIndexChanging fires" Yes but it fires twice and my question for confirmation is showed twice. The code inserted in my edit is only to show you my current solution. I'm trying to get the same result using your answer (but help is needed)

Comment: The code in the Edit is using the standard event, not the new one that CBO provides.  It doesnt look like you are using it from the code shown.  The CBO should do all the restore-to-previous-index for you.  It internalizes that.  The `SelectedIndexChanged` event code should just go ahead and do whatever - you already asked before hand

Comment: @Plutonix It's exactly what I'm saying (sorry if I'm not clear) please look at my 2nd edit

Comment: @Plutonix I know that I can use the same logic of the boolean but, usually, when an event is cancelled, isn't fired twice, so I would like to have the same effect. But if isn't possible I'll use the boolean. (Anyway I'll accept)

Comment: Cannot duplicate - it fires once only.  However, the `Messagebox` is **modal** and displaying them in event handlers can create problems.  If you watch, the selected item will change momentarily while the MsgBox is open.  If you cancel, **then** it goes back.  If you still have code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event it will already be queued to fire.  There ought not be a Msgbox in that event, since you already asked/tested/qualified everything.

Comment: ...and if *you* are setting/resetting the index in the standard `SelectedIndexChanged` event for some reason, that will start the cycle over including the new event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do most of what you want.  It subclasses `ComboBox` to add a new event which fires before the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  If you cancel, then that event does not fire.

```
Public Class SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Cancel As Boolean = False
    Public Property NewIndex As Int32 = -1

    Friend Sub New(index As Int32)
        NewIndex = index
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class ComboBoxEx
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private selectedObject As Object = Nothing

    Public Event SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object, 
                            e As SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
        Dim evArgs As New SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs(MyBase.SelectedIndex)
        RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanging(Me, evArgs)

        If evArgs.Cancel Then
            If selectedObject IsNot Nothing Then
                MyBase.SelectedIndex = MyBase.Items.IndexOf(selectedObject)
            Else
                MyBase.SelectedIndex = -1
            End If
            Return       ' do not fire Changed event
        End If

        MyBase.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)
        selectedObject = MyBase.Items(MyBase.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It just internalizes the logic you probably already have, but if there are more than one "cancel-able" controls on the form, you wont have to have multiple index tracking variables.  Maybe that is simpler.

Usage:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxEx1_SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object,
          e As SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs) Handles ComboBoxEx1.SelectedIndexChanging
    If ComboBoxEx1.Items(e.NewIndex).ToString.Contains("o") Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the `Items` collection can be modified, a simple `LastIndex` variable may not be enough - it could refer to the wrong item after something is added or removed. This tracks the last object selected and tries to find it in the current list.

It also works with a `DataSource`, but there are probably a number of other situations to be accounted for.

Comment: I'm reading your code (later I'll try to test it in my form) +1 for giving much more every time

Comment: I don't know if it's my fault, but I wasn't able to use this solution. I tried many ways: 1) adding code after the end of my class (in the code windows of my form); 2) adding a class with your code; 3) adding a 'component class' with your code. The result it's always the same: I found the new ComboBoxEx but, when I try to insert it, I get error and a message says that the component will be removed from list (because unable to load it)

Comment: Just add  class (not component) to the project, and add the code there.  After you compile the project it will be added to the toolbox

Comment: Ok, done! (The bug was that I didn't compile before adding the control). Now I'm trying to avoid that the event is run twice: when I cancel, the command `MyBase.SelectedIndex = MyBase.Items.IndexOf(selectedObject)` makes the confirmation is asked twice. I'm trying to find a solution ... (any help is appreciated) because I can't use the same logic of my current code (see my update question)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the currently selected item in a global variable like

```
Dim selected As Object
```

Then on the DropDown event of the ComboBox you can set this equal to what the currently selected item by doing.

```
selected = ComboBox.SelectedItem
```

Then on your SelectedIndexChanged event when you don't want it to change you can simlpy set the selected item back.

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = selected
```

There are probably more cleaner ways but this was just off the top of my head.

If you didn't want to store the whole object and just the index you can use .SelectedIndex and declare the variable as an Integer instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'm trying to avoid that the event is run twice: when I cancel, the command MyBase.SelectedIndex = MyBase.Items.IndexOf(selectedObject) makes the confirmation is asked twice.

For those coming across this now, I've added a numbing piece of code that stops it from firing the second time. I believe this will work fine with multiple comboboxes, but it happens so quick that it should be fine if it doesn't, or if you are only using one like me.

```
Public Class SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Cancel As Boolean = False
    Public Property NewIndex As Int32 = -1

    Friend Sub New(index As Int32)
        NewIndex = index
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class ComboBoxEx

    Inherits ComboBox

    Private selectedObject As Object = Nothing

    Private Property Numb As Boolean = False

    Public Event SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object,
                                e As SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
        Dim evArgs As New SelectedIndexChangingEventArgs(MyBase.SelectedIndex)

        If Numb = False Then

            RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanging(Me, evArgs)

        Else

            Numb = False

        End If

        If evArgs.Cancel Then
            If selectedObject IsNot Nothing Then

                Numb = True

                MyBase.SelectedIndex = MyBase.Items.IndexOf(selectedObject)
            Else
                MyBase.SelectedIndex = -1
            End If
            Return       ' do not fire Changed event
        End If

        MyBase.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)
        selectedObject = MyBase.Items(MyBase.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just in case it is useful to anyone :P